# Security differencies storing value in cookies.signed vs. session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

I'm looking to have a more persistent logged-in experience for the users, so I want to save the user's `id` with `cookies.signed[:id] = user.id` instead of `session[:id] = user.id`.

Are there any security implications with this change that I should be aware of (different encryption etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an example. Let's work through very Bad Scenario. Someone got your app' secret for signing cookies. So, these bad people will be able to store the data they want in the cookie. If you will identify users by id in cookie, they will be able to sign in as any user in the system. How? Well, most of apps use integer starting with 0 for ids, right? It will be pretty easy to find, for example, admin user with id 1. What if you will identify users by session? Sessions (just like cookies) usually expire. Even more - it will be pretty annoying to guess session id of admin or someone else (and even impossible if these users have no session at all). I'm not saying what you're perfectly safe if someone stole your app' secret and you store only session id in cookies. But it's definitely better to store user id in a session, rather than storing it in cookie.